# Switching pages after Zeroclipboard copies text

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I've seen quite a few posts about zeroclipboard, but unfortunately the replies have not been helpful (understandable) to a script newbie like me. I have a page with a bunch of coupons on it. When someone clicks on a coupon, I want to copy the coupon's CODE and then take them to the coupon's LINK. I can get the CODE to copy in the alert, but I can't figure out how to then take them to the url I specify in each coupon's LINK. Can someone show me a way to do this? Here's my code...

```
<section style="position:relative">
<div id="sliders" style="margin:0 auto; width: auto; height:auto;">
    <div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
        <div id="slider1" class="items">

            <div onclick="window.open('http://url-one.com','_blank');"> <!--THERE ARE SEVERAL OF THESE-->
                html...
                <div id="clip_container1">
                    <p id="coupon1" link="url-one.com" onMouseOver="move_swf(this)">copytext1</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<script>
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( '<?= base_url("resource/js/ZeroClipboard.swf");?>' );
var clip = null;
//  function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } //not needed?
function init() 
{
    clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
    clip.setHandCursor( true );
    clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
        alert("Copied Coupon Code to your clipboard:\n" + text);
//          now open "link" in a new window...;   
    });
   }

function move_swf(ee)
{ 
   copything = document.getElementById(ee.id+"").innerHTML;
   clip.setText(copything.substring(23));
      if (clip.div)
     {    
         clip.receiveEvent('mouseout', null);
         clip.reposition(ee.id);
      }
      else{ clip.glue(ee.id);   
      }
      clip.receiveEvent('mouseover', null);
 }    
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the desired DOM element by the coupon code it contains
(assuming coupon codes are unique)

Add something like this below the alert code:

(assuming jquery in the lines of code I added):

```
clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
    alert("Copied Coupon Code to your clipboard:\n" + text);

    //Add the two lines below

    var mylink = jQuery( "p:contains(" + text + ")" ).attr('link'); 
    myWhateverOpenSesameFunctionToOpenMyLink(mylink);
});
```